# Unable to get RF detector to work with Sequent Microsystems HAT and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect an RF detector and a device that can increase its sensitivity to the HAT which is connected to the Raspberry PI. When attaching the HAT to the Pi, the power LED lights up on the HAT displaying that power is transferred, and when the RF detector is attached to the HAT the power LED on the detector lights up as well showing that it receives power. Despite this, the output from the RF detector is not reaching the HAT and is not being displayed on the board or by using the 16inpind-rpi library that comes with the HAT.I believe I have the system wired correctly, just attaching positives and negatives together, and am not sure why the outputs are not working.

[image]

I know that this picture is very crude, but I have the power outputs from the Pi attaching to the bread board and connecting to both components. And the output of the RF detector is attached to input 1 of the HAT. When running this block of code it shows the channel 1 is receiving no inputs even though the detector is attached to the input 1 slot.

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lib16inpind
>>> lib16inpind.readCh(0, 1)
0
>>>
```

Comment: To debug and make sure you can talk to lib16inpind library and that the Sequent HAT is working.  Can you verify that you can read +5V if you run a jumper from +5V to input? It's not obvious that anything is wrong with your setup from the picture.